# UVA Online Judge is returning runtime error that I can't reproduce

Tags: c++

I am working on problem 00156, Anagrams.

I complied the code and it works perfectly fine on my side, but when i upload the code, it returns runtime error on the online judge.

I would like to understand where the error is, but I am quite new at C++, so please keep it simple, thank you in advance.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector< string > ws, wf, wl;
    char wd[80]; scanf("%s", &wd);
    while(strcmp(wd, "#")){
        ws.push_back(wd);
        scanf("%s", &wd);
    }

    char *w;
    for(int i=0; i<ws.size(); i++){
        strcpy(w, (char*) ws.at(i).c_str());
        for(int j=0; j<strlen(w); j++) w[j] = (char) tolower(w[j]);
        sort(w, w+strlen(w));
        wf.push_back(w);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<ws.size(); i++){
        if(count(wf.begin(), wf.end(), wf.at(i))==1) wl.push_back(ws.at(i));
    }
    sort(wl.begin(), wl.end());

    for(int i=0; i<wl.size(); i++){
        printf("%s\n", wl.at(i).c_str());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add the text of the run-time error message to your post.

Comment: the run-time error message is not provided on the online judge, but the code produces no error and runs perfectly fine on my machine.

Answer (score 3):

Here is your first error:

```
char wd[80]; scanf("%s", &wd);
```

This is undefined behavior.  This is not how you use scanf() for string data.  You are passing the address of the array instead of the address of the first element of the array (or even easier, just passing the name):

```
char wd[80]; scanf("%s", wd);
```

Second error:

```
char *w;
for(int i=0; i<ws.size(); i++){
    strcpy(w, (char*) ws.at(i).c_str());
```

w is an uninitialized pointer, yet you are filling what it points to with characters from ws.  This is again, undefined behavior.

As to you being new to C++, put down the C books and learn C++ properly.  Why are you using strcpy(), char arrays, and all sorts of C-isms in your code?  Why not just use std::string for everything?  Your first two errors would not have happened if you used std::string (for the first error, a usage of getline() instead of scanf() would have helped also).

Here is a rewrite of your code using std::string:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
//...

vector< string > ws, wf, wl;
string wd;
getline(cin, wd);
while(wd != "#")
{
    ws.push_back(wd);
    getline(cin, wd);
}

string w;
for(size_t i=0; i<ws.size(); ++i)
{
    w = ws[i];
    transform(w.begin(), w.end(), w.begin(), ::tolower);
    sort(w.begin(), w.end());
    wf.push_back(w);
}
```

Now does this solve your anagram problem?  I don't know.  The point is that the code will *not* crash or has undefined behavior.  Every line you see above is well-defined, there are no "off by one" errors, no pointers to mess up, nothing.  The input is not limited to 80 characters, no mistake-prone scanf()'s, etc..

If there is any issue, it is now confined in getting your algorithm/program to do the job, and not fighting with pointers and other issues that gets you side-tracked.

Comment: thanks for the answer, why does the code not return a runtime error on my machine, but does for the online judge?

Comment: Undefined behavior.  If you overrun memory, there is no guarantee how your program will run or behave.